# Map from list of maps

Tags: clojure

My problem is next, i have list of maps, for example:

```
({:id 1 :request-count 10 ..<another key-value pair>..} 
 {:id 2 :request-count 15 ..<another key-value pair>..} 
 ...)
```

Need create map with records in which, key is value of 'id'  and value is value of 'request-count', for each map from prev example, like:

```
{1 10
 2 15
 ...}
```

I know how to do this. My question is - standard library have function for achieve this? Or maybe i can achiev this with combination few function, without 'reduce'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `juxt` function to generate a sequence of pairs, and then toss them into a map:

```
(into {} (map (juxt :id :request-count) data))
```

Example:

```
user=> (def data [{:id 1 :request-count 10 :abc 1}
  #_=>            {:id 2 :request-count 15 :def 2}
  #_=>            {:id 3 :request-count 20 :ghi 3}])
#'user/data
user=> (into {} (map (juxt :id :request-count) data))
{1 10, 2 15, 3 20}
```

Be aware that if there is more than one map in `data` with the same `:id`, then the last one encountered by `map` will be the one that survives in the output map.

Comment: Nice approach, thank you! "Be aware that if there is more than one..." Thx, i know it:).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so:

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :request-count 10}
   {:id 2 :request-count 15}]  )

(defn make-id-req-map [map-seq]
  (vec (for [curr-map map-seq]
         (let [{:keys [id request-count]} curr-map]
           {id request-count}))))
```

With result:

```
(make-id-req-map data) => [{1 10} {2 15}]
```

Note: while you could combine the map destructuring into the `for` statement, I usually like to label the intermediate values as described in Martin Fowler's refactoring "Introduce Explaining Variable".

Comment: I think is same as use 'reduce', many code. I looking for short approach. Thanks for idea.

Comment: Yes, `for` and `map` are 2 ways of doing the same thing. `reduce` is like `map` but can carry state from each iteration to the next (i.e. it is just `map` with an accumulator).

Comment: @AlanThompson `reduce` accumulates one value. `map` performs a one-to-one translation of a sequence (or the transpose of several sequences) into another sequence. `reduce` *may* produce a sequence. `map` always does so. They are not alike.